# Why is a Rails app loading extremely slow with Docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I am exploring the world of Docker and decided to test it for an empty Rails app.

Here's my `Dockerize` file:

```
FROM ruby:alpine

RUN apk add --update build-base postgresql-dev tzdata nodejs yarn
RUN gem install rails -v '5.1.6'

WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/
RUN bundle install
RUN yarn install
```

here the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: puma
    ports:
      - 3003:3003
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@db
  db:
    image: postgres:10.3-alpine
```

and here the `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'webpacker'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'react-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I was used to that when I wanted to start a Rails app, I ran the following in the terminal tab: `rails s -p 3003`. Now, with Docker, I run this:
`docker-compose up` or `docker-compose up -d` and go to `0.0.0.0:3003`and after 20-50 seconds (!) is loaded this page. Why is the loading time so slow? Can I somehow speed it up?

The app is literarily empty, it's only connected to PSQL and there's a controller with a `Hello World` action.

Comment: What platform are you running on? macOS for example is [notoriously slow](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2659) for filesystem operations, and that could easily explain this.

Comment: Yes, I am on OSX.

Comment: Then I recommend Googling "macOS Docker file system slow" and attempting any of the many many workarounds. I usually install Linux through Virtual Machine and run Docker within that rather than directly on macOS.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `volumes:` line that mounts your application code into the container.  This avoids the aforementioned performance issue, and means that the container you're running locally is identical to what you'll run in production; it doesn't depend on your local source tree at all.

Answer (score 0):

I run docker on Mac with no issues and suspect that it's your Dockerfile running bundler and reinstalling your gemlist every time you run `docker-compose up`.  Separate copying the gemfile and copying the rest of your app because Docker will cache it thus preventing recopying the gemfile everytime you make a change and rebuild the app. It will only reinstall gems when you change the gemfile and rebuild.  Also, use "COPY" instead of "ADD" whenever possible because "ADD" does some extra magic like unpacking Tar files and fetching files from remote urls etc.

```
RUN gem install bundler
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --binstubs

#Left dot signifies copies everything from workstation in current directory of the Dockerfile.  Right dot means it will be copied into the current containers working directory.  It also checks for a file called .dockerignore and will skip copying anything inside those folders.
COPY . .
```

**For a reference**, I commented up a dockerfile for a local app I built.

```
FROM ruby:2.3-slim

MAINTAINER Brian <wasup@gmail.com>

#Always run apt-get update and apt-get install in same line because the update can be cached and thus may not run on second build.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential wkhtmltopdf libxrender1 libxext6 libfontconfig1 imagemagick nodejs libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.4 --fix-missing --no-install-recommends

ENV INSTALL_PATH /kunzig

#the p flag allows for installing into a sub-path which isnt necessary here
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

#All commands run after this run in the context of this work path
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

#Left hand side is gemfile from workstation, right hand side is path in docker container (in this case kunzig/Gemfile since workdir is /kunzig already we can just do Gemfile)
RUN gem install bundler
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --binstubs

#Left dot signifies copies everything from workstation in current directory of the Dockerfile.  Right dot means it will be copied into the current containers working directory (kunzig).  It also checks for a file called .dockerignore and will skip copying anything inside those folders.
COPY . .

#Note:  Always separate copying the gemfile and copying the rest because Docker will cache it thus preventing recopying the gemfile everytime you make a change and rebuild the app. and only reinstall gems when you change the gemfile and rebuild!

#When running this from Docker it needs dummy filler for the db and token so just made some stuff up so it doesnt error...
RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL='postgresql://kunzig:bjkbjk@postgres:5432/kunzig?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=5000' SECRET_KEY_BASE=somejdfkpicksomething assets:precompile

#This volume will allow us to expose our assets in the public folder to nginx since nginx will be sitting in front of the rails app and serve our assets.  Volume creation must go LAST on the dockerfile since everything after isn't run except CMD.
VOLUME ["$INSTALL_PATH/public"]

#Can swap in Puma via this one line if desired
CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```